# Keras monitor on val_recall reports not improve although it is improving

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Monitoring Keras metric of val_reall. It has been improving but it keeps the best value as the lowest 0.9958 although better values 0.9978 or 0.9985 have been recorded. The monitor mode is set to 'auto'.

Please help understand why the Keras thinks the metric is not improving.

```
Epoch 1/10
6883/6883 [==============================] - 1982s 287ms/step - loss: 0.1025 - recall: 0.9738 - accuracy: 0.9631 - val_loss: 0.0537 - val_recall: 0.9978 - val_accuracy: 0.9837

Epoch 00001: val_recall improved from inf to 0.99783, saving model to /content/drive/MyDrive/home/repository/mon/kaggle/toxic_comment_classification/toxicity_classification_2021JUL10_1647/model_Ctoxic_B32_L256/model.h5
Epoch 2/10
6883/6883 [==============================] - 1970s 286ms/step - loss: 0.0348 - recall: 0.9946 - accuracy: 0.9901 - val_loss: 0.0412 - val_recall: 0.9958 - val_accuracy: 0.9888

Epoch 00002: val_recall improved from 0.99783 to 0.99583, saving model to /content/drive/MyDrive/home/repository/mon/kaggle/toxic_comment_classification/toxicity_classification_2021JUL10_1647/model_Ctoxic_B32_L256/model.h5
Epoch 3/10
6883/6883 [==============================] - 1970s 286ms/step - loss: 0.0181 - recall: 0.9968 - accuracy: 0.9952 - val_loss: 0.0446 - val_recall: 0.9984 - val_accuracy: 0.9897

Epoch 00003: val_recall did not improve from 0.99583
Epoch 4/10
6883/6883 [==============================] - 1972s 286ms/step - loss: 0.0125 - recall: 0.9976 - accuracy: 0.9967 - val_loss: 0.0429 - val_recall: 0.9985 - val_accuracy: 0.9902

Epoch 00004: val_recall did not improve from 0.99583
Epoch 5/10
6883/6883 [==============================] - 1973s 287ms/step - loss: 0.0094 - recall: 0.9979 - accuracy: 0.9974 - val_loss: 0.0663 - val_recall: 0.9991 - val_accuracy: 0.9873

Epoch 00005: ReduceLROnPlateau reducing learning rate to 5.9999998484272515e-06.

Epoch 00005: val_recall did not improve from 0.99583
Epoch 6/10
6883/6883 [==============================] - 1970s 286ms/step - loss: 0.0031 - recall: 0.9996 - accuracy: 0.9993 - val_loss: 0.0646 - val_recall: 0.9998 - val_accuracy: 0.9901

Epoch 00006: val_recall did not improve from 0.99583
Epoch 7/10
6883/6883 [==============================] - 1967s 286ms/step - loss: 0.0019 - recall: 0.9998 - accuracy: 0.9997 - val_loss: 0.0641 - val_recall: 0.9997 - val_accuracy: 0.9903
Restoring model weights from the end of the best epoch.

Epoch 00007: val_recall did not improve from 0.99583
Epoch 00007: early stopping
```

### Solution

As per the comment by Innat, `mode=max` at callbacks.

Comment: set monitor to `max`.

Answer (score 0):

From Comments:

> Setting `mode=max` in the Callbacks has resolved the issue.